# Given a finite field of primer order and a certain degree extension, how one finds the "best" irreducible polynomial in terms of computability?

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Assume that I have a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ of prime order $p$, that is $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$. Let's also assume that I fix a certain integer $e$ that will act as the degree of the extension I am looking to work on.

It is of common knowledge that to obtain the extension field of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of order $e$, denoted $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$, I have to first find an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $e$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ and from this polynomial one obtains that $\mathbb{F}_{p^e} = \mathbb{F}_p[X] / (f)$.

My question concerns the election of the irreducible polynomial: Assuming it exists, how can I obtain the polynomial that produces the best arithmetic in the extension? I.e., I am looking for the polynomial that gives me the most efficient arithmetic in terms of time, meaning that I use as few field elements as possible in the computation of the multiplication of two elements in the extension, for example.

I have seen that the [Conway polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polynomial_(finite_fields)) are the standard way of choosing the irreducible polynomial and that they have some special properties, but I think that they are not the best polynomials for what I am looking for.

Comment: You probably want a polynomial with as many zero coefficients as possible. But I doubt there is an easy way to find this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So, if it exitst, are you saying that the best I can hope for is a polynomial of the form $aX^e + b$ (ideally $a=b=1$)?

Comment: Well, you can always choose $a=1.$ But there will often be cases where there is no polynomial of the form $X^e+b$ which is irreducible. Most obviously, when $e$ is divisible by $p.$ But also more generally when $e$ is divisible by a prime which is not a factor of $p-1.$

Comment: For example, $p=11, e=3,$ then $x^3+b$ is always divisible by $x+b^{7}.$

Comment: This is, indeed, difficult in general. As Thomas Andrews explained, binomials won't always do. People have seriously looked at ways of locating irreducible trinomials. That theory is something I am not familiar with, but IIRC it won't cover all the $(p,e)$ pairs either. The case of $p=2$, $e$ relatively large, has been looked at by people implementing cryptosystems based on finite fields with $2^e$ elements, where $e$ is somewhere between $160$ and $500$ or some such range. Instead of using an irreducible polynomial they are looking for bases with as simple multiplication tables as possible.

Comment: (cont'd) And *normal bases* are then particularly attractive because the Galois group acts transitively on the bases elements, and you only need to store a fraction of the multiplication table due to the resulting cyclic symmetry. So called optimal normal bases are few and far between, but reasonably good normal bases can be found more often. A common technique is to look for a root of unity of prime order $q$ such that $q=ke+1$ with $k$ as small as possible, and $2$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}_q^*$. You get optimal normal bases when $k\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: (cont'd) As $k$ grows the resulting bases gradually yield more complex multiplication tables, but they are often better than what you get with using an irreducible polynomial. I am not familiar enough with the theory to explain it all, and it is anything but clear that the process works in your case. You can use $p$ in place of $2$. Anyway, a summary of my impression is that *it depends on the exact $(p,e)$ pair* :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What do you exactly mean with "simple" multiplication tables? I suppose that this means that the the number of base field multiplications is as few as possible, right?

Comment: @BeanGuy  If $x_i$ and $x_j$ are two elements of a given basis, we can write their product as a linear combination of the basis elements: $x_ix_j=\sum_k c_{ijk} x_k$. A measure of simplicity is then the number of non-zero coefficients $c_{ijk}$. A problem with using a basis of residue classes of monomials $x^i$ modulo $f(x)$ is that while $i+j<e$ everything is as simple as it can be, in the other half of the multiplication table matters soon develop uncontrollably. True, if $f$ is a suitable trinomial, initially it won't be too bad.

Comment: (cont'd) But using normal bases like above (with a low $k$ when possible) the number of non-zero coefficients $c_{ijk}$ for a fixed pair $(i,j)$ remains bounded by a constant (maximum of $2$ and $k$ IIRC). Furthermore, with a normal bases we have $c_{i+\ell, j+\ell,k+\ell}=c_{i,j,k}$, subscript arithmetic modulo $e$. Meaning that we don't need to store all of $c_{i,jk}$. For example, it suffices to store $c_{0,j,k}$ and the rest are there. Once more, I don't know if this helps you.

Comment: Re: storage. Let's not forget that when using a monomial basis it similarly suffices to store the cosets $x^n+(f)$, $e\le n\le2(e-1),$ in terms of the lowest powers of $x$. For large $e$ the difference (to good or optimal normal bases) comes from these becoming "random" in a large enough corner.